# Merging a dataframe with each element in a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list with 4 groups each group has 2 variables including a date variable, however, the groups have different lengths, here is a sample. I'm also hoping to forecast this data.

```
 Date              Invoice Final Payment POS
  2019-02-03                     24.00
  2019-02-04                   1160.23
  2019-02-05                     29.52
  2019-02-06                     45.25
  2019-02-07                     81.75
  2019-02-10                     39.50
  2019-02-11                     24.00
  2019-02-12                     77.00
  2019-02-16                     37.50
  2019-02-17                    191.1
```

I also have a dataset with one variable of dates from 2019-02-02 to 2021-01-05, it would look like this.

```
          Date
1   2019-02-02
2   2019-02-03
3   2019-02-04
4   2019-02-05
5   2019-02-06
6   2019-02-07
7   2019-02-08
8   2019-02-09
9   2019-02-10
10  2019-02-11
11  2019-02-12
12  2019-02-13
13  2019-02-14
14  2019-02-15
15  2019-02-16
16  2019-02-17
```

My problem is that because the list data doesn't have all the observations between 2019-02-02 to 2021-01-05 I end up with inconsistent observations, what I'm hoping to do is to merge both the data frame and elements within the list, so dates with no observations are just 0.

What I hope I can produce is this.

```
         Date              Invoice Final Payment POS
      2019-02-02                       0
      2019-02-03                     24.00
      2019-02-04                   1160.23
      2019-02-05                     29.52
      2019-02-06                     45.25
      2019-02-07                     81.75
      2019-02-08                       0
      2019-02-09                       0
      2019-02-10                     39.50
      2019-02-11                     24.00
      2019-02-12                     77.00
      2019-02-13                       0
      2019-02-14                       0
      2019-02-15                       0
      2019-02-16                     37.50
      2019-02-17                    191.1
```

I've tried many methods but none of them works, it is vital that I maintain the list and not merge the groups back together.

If there's a method to solve this problem, please help?

I'm really sorry I couldn't use `dput()`

Comment: Could you please share the two datasets using dput()? If the data is too long, you can use dput(head(<your_data>, 20)). Ideally, please also include explicitly what output you are looking for.

Comment: I have edited the question, I'm really sorry that I couldn't use dput().

Comment: I don't understand why you can't use dput to share the data. But in principle something like `new_data <- full_join(dates, invoice)`. It'll have a bunch of NA, but you can then replace those with 0.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the `merge` statement with the `all.x` & `all.y` options.

Below a working example:

```
library(tidyverse)

Date <- c('2019-02-02','2019-02-03','2019-02-07','2019-02-05','2019-02-10')
Invoice_Final_Payment_POS <- c(563.53,269.50,43.00,42.00,34.00)
list <- data.frame(Date,Invoice_Final_Payment_POS)

DateRange <- c('2019-02-02','2019-02-03','2019-02-04','2019-02-05','2019-02-06')
DateRange <- data.frame(DateRange)

df <- merge(DateRange, list, by.x = "DateRange", by.y = "Date", all.x = TRUE, all.y = TRUE)
df[is.na(df)] = 0
df

      DateRange Invoice_Final_Payment_POS
1 2019-02-02                    563.53
2 2019-02-03                    269.50
3 2019-02-04                      0.00
4 2019-02-05                     42.00
5 2019-02-06                      0.00
6 2019-02-07                     43.00
7 2019-02-10                     34.00
```